# Allow file downloading with routes in Codeigniter

Tags: file, routes, codeigniter-3

I have this route defined `$route['download/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'download/index/$1/$2';`
What I want is, `mydomain.com/download/444/filename.mp3`. Now problem is when I pass the url without extension `.mp3` it works fine, but when I give url with `.mp3` it shows `404` of `nginx`. i.e.

```
mydomain.com/download/444/filename.mp3 ERROR
mydomain.com/download/444/filename SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem:

```
$route['download/(:num)/([a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = 'download/index/$1/$2';
```

I Hope it will help you.